# how can I combine two list together in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, global

Hi I'm trying to combine both list together in python therefore the output will be ['apple', 'cherry']. I only get this [] as an answer but I'm trying to get the output of 'apple and cherry added together. Thanks in Advance.

```
FruitArr = []
VeggieArr = []


def one():
list1 = ["apple", "beans", "cabbage", "broccoli"]
if 'apple' in list1:
    FruitArr.append('apple')
print(FruitArr)


def two():
list2 = ["rice", "carrot", "garlic", "cherry"]
if 'cherry' in list2:
    VeggieArr.append('cherry')
print(VeggieArr)

listcombined = FruitArr + VeggieArr

print(listcombined)

# OUTPUT ['apple','cherry']
```

Comment: You forgot to write your question

Comment: I think you got a bunch of things wrong, why are you defining functions? why are the lists defined in the function where you already know 'apple' will be in list1?? why are you appending to a global list?

Comment: also you are never calling your unindented functions one and two, that might be your issue

Comment: Hi, What's the issue you're facing in here?

Comment: why are you defining 2 methods in your code , while not calling it anywhere ?? you can do this code without defining them inside methods OR call the methods you've defined

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in FruitArr:
    VeggieArr.append(i)
```

Or use `extend()` which would look like

```
FruitArr.extend(VeggieArr)
```

Also make sure the functions are being called from somewhere in order to reach the code.